# ORMLite + Transactions

Tags: transactions, ormlite

I have a problem understanding the default behavior of the DaoManager.

```
DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, theClass);
```

This takes a connectionSource - not a connection.
So if I do the following:

```
TransactionManager.callInTransaction(
    localConnection,
    connectionSource.getDatabaseType(),
    new Callable<Void>() {
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            dao.create(user);
            dao.create(player);
                return null;
            }
    });
```

The transaction should be limited to a single connection (the localConnection). How does the DAO handle that? Or does it not handle it at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The transaction should be limited to a single connection (the localConnection). How does the DAO handle that? Or does it not handle it at all?

Hrm.  I'm not 100% sure why the connection method is exposed.  I'm going to deprecate it.

You really should be using the [`dao.callBatchTasks(...)` method](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#callBatchTasks(java.util.concurrent.Callable)).  If you need to use the `TransactionManager` directly, I'd use the [method that takes a `ConnectionSource`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/misc/TransactionManager.html#callInTransaction(com.j256.ormlite.support.ConnectionSource,%20java.util.concurrent.Callable)), *not* a connection.

You can take a look at the [source of `TransactionManager.callInTransaction(...)`](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/misc/TransactionManager.java#L134) to see that it is saving the connection which then is used by the DAO later through some ORMLite magic.  So auto-commit is disabled on the saved connection and then restored after the batch tasks complete.

Comment: Thank you! I wrote my post before this comment so... I will take a look at callBatchTasks-method. Maybe there is already an example... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I analyzed the codebase and it seems that if I use the same ConnectionSource when initially requesting the dao internally a "savedConnection" is established which is then forced to be used.

If anybody could confirm/refute this - or simly knows how to do it fully right - please tell me!